# Employing file geodatabase that is going to be used and edited by multiple users

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, file-geodatabase, data-management

I have a file geodatabase that contains 3 feature classes in it and each feature class contains a lot of data that will be viewed and edited daily by 6 other users.  I am looking for any advice from people who have been in the same situation and the best practices to avoid edit lock outs and to keep everything running smoothly as possible.

Are there any open source tools I can use that will enable multi user editing on a file geodatabase?

My work only has ArcView level licencing with a couple extensions (Business Analyst, Network Analyst and Spatial Analyst)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree,
Attempting to utilize the proprietary (fgdb or pgdb) db format created by esri and managed through their licensing is a fruitless path. If you are determined to not spend license money you will spend resource (your time and the time of other employees) money. What you are proposing is doable with an opensource rdbms or a proprietary lite version of rdbms, and some interoperable tools (most of the good ones though are not free). So in the long run you either need some expensive experience or some good tools, both are costly. Arcview just is not the tool to get-er-done.
[Task functionality matrix](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis10-desktop-functionality-matrix.pdf)

Answer (score 9):

Use a file GDB as the master (on server), extract COPY to 6 personal GDB (2GB limit) or 6 FGDB if over 2GB. Individuals edit each GDB then place in folder with a template FILE Geodatabase [empty but has schema set up] for nightly [APPEND](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000050000000.htm) (geoprocessing server)

Schema
TEST —Input dataset schema (field definitions) must match the schema of the target dataset. An error will be returned if the schemas do not match.

Disadvantage: 
Data Conflicts - One Feature Multiple edits by 2 plus users. Append will overwrite previous appended file. Can be detected by a [compare](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Compare_Layer_to_Snapshot/010900000016000000/) < this is cheaper than getting an Arc Info licence.

Successfully implemented in a previous role...

Can be also achieved with [FME 2010](http://www.safe.com/products/desktop/overview.php)

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't attempt this with a fGDB. It'll be one headache after another. If you need multi-user editing, you should go with an SDE GDB. If you've only got six editors, workgroup SDE would work well for you. From the [ArcGIS 10 documentation:  Types of geodatabases](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n00000007000000.htm)

> ArcGIS Server Workgroup also includes
>   ArcSDE support for SQL Server Express.
>   With this level of ArcSDE, you can use
>   SQL Server Express for up to 10
>   simultaneous Windows desktop users and
>   editors (users of ArcView, ArcEditor,
>   ArcInfo, a custom ArcGIS Engine
>   application, AutoCAD, MicroStation,
>   and so on) plus any number of
>   additional server connections from Web
>   applications. (Consult your license
>   agreement for specific information on
>   the number of connections for your
>   implementation.)

Answer (score 5):

This cannot be done with ArcView. (Editing the same PGDB/FGDB by several users at the same time.) Look into to upgrading to ArcEditor: ArcEditor allows multiple users to simultaneously modify and edit data.
http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arceditor/key-features.html

*As a side note; I was involved with developing an application where we tried to emulate multi-user editing with personal databases and it ended up being fairly complex with mixed results. The reasoning was the same; a multi-user database was too costly. It ended up costing a lot more trying to develop such environment. In the end it would have been better to invest into ArcSDE or like solution.*